# Demonstrate C# Convoy Lock

Tags: c#, locking

A Couple of years back due to a improperly implemented "Try Catch Finally" block the development team struggled with a runtime freeze which was later discovered as a case of Convoy Lock Issue.

I am looking for a simple C# code to demonstrate a Convoy Locking to my fellow team mates.

Any help for a code sample would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concurrent Programming on Windows has some great content on this subject which you could take to the team.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/032143482X/ref=ox_ya_oh_product](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X)

Comment: Thanks Paul.. I am browsing through the same book at Safari.